# @Bean Controller not getting picked up by @EnableMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

Most of my @Controllers are picked up through component scanning. However, a few, such as those I use with Spring Social are created as @Beans. I just migrated from mostly xml to JavaConfig only and upgraded to Spring 4.1.9.

However, the Controller endpoints that are created as @Beans are creating 404s.

Any ideas?

```
package nl.project.webapp.config;

@Order(1)
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServletConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    [...]
}

package nl.project.webapp.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"nl.project.webapp"},excludeFilters={
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=Controller.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=RestController.class)
})
@Import({AppConfig.class,JPAConfig.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:msa.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {
    [...]
}

package nl.project.webapp.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"nl.project.webapp.controller"},includeFilters={
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=Controller.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=RestController.class)    
})
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
   [...]    
}

package nl.project.webapp.social.config;

@Configuration
public class SocialConfig{

    @Bean
    public MyConnectController connectController(MessageSource messages, UsorManager userMgr, PhotoManager photoMgr) {

        MyConnectController connectController = new MyConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        connectController.setConnectInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new ConnectInterceptor<?>[]{
            new TwitterConnectInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr, messages),
            new FacebookConnectInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr, messages),
            new LinkedInConnectInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr, messages),
            new GoogleConnectInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr, messages),
        }));

        return connectController;
    }

    @Bean 
    public MySignInController signinController(MessageSource messages, UsorManager userMgr, PhotoManager photoMgr){

        MySignInController signinController = new MySignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSigninAdapter(userMgr));
        signinController.setSignInInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new ProviderSignInInterceptor<?>[]{
            new FacebookSigninInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr, messages),
            new LinkedInSigninInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr),
            new GoogleSigninInterceptor(userMgr, photoMgr)
        }));

        return signinController;
    }

}


package nl.project.webapp.social.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/signin")
public class MySignInController extends ProviderSignInController {

    public MySignInController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository,
            SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
        this.connectionFactoryLocator = connectionFactoryLocator;

    }

[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by SocialConfig being imported by the WebAppConfig in stead of the ServletConfig. Although the documentation suggests that any Controller bean available in the context will be picked up by using '@EnableWebMVC', it is not very clear that this does not apply to Controller beans loaded through the webapp context.